# "the method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity"

Tags: java, android, cordova

I apologize if I'm missing something simple here, but this is my first time using java and I'm stumped.

```
    public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

The error message I get:

```
    The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity
```

thanks

Comment: Do you have the support library imported? `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

Comment: Is DroidGap a `FragmentActivity`? Since `getSupportFragmentManager()`(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager%28%29) is part of the FragmentActivity. If it's not, then DroidGap needs to extend FragmentActivity.

Comment: Yes, support library is imported.
How would I extend FragmentActivity?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your are using phonegap library to load an url ( similar to web view).

Change your

```
 getSupportFragmentManager // with android support library
```

to

```
getFragmentManager().
```

Since...

```
DroidGap extends PhonegapActivity
```

and

```
PhonegapActivity extends Activity
```

http://raphael-lemaire.com/phonegapjavadocs/com/phonegap/DroidGap.html

*Note : DroidGap seems to be deprecated*

Comment: Well I did that, now I'm getting a new error code:
"The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment)"

Comment: Make sure PlaceholderFragment extends android.app.Fragment (not the fragment class in support library)

Comment: Why do u add fragment?, you have not set content view to activity. R.Id.container framelayout should be in layout to add fragment